# Selenium: Why does chromedriver.exe randomly "freeze", failing my tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-testing

**Given:**

- All the below are on Windows 10 / Server 2012 R2
- Selenium .Net (C#) tests (Selenium.WebDriver nuget v3.141.0, .Net Framework v4.8)
- ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70
- Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Tests run automatically by Azure DevOps Server (installed on-prem)

**When:**

Seemingly randomly once every few hours (one out of every few dozens of tests runs)

**Then:**

ChromeDriver logs seem to show it freezing for ~70-90 seconds and then resuming. Please see log snippet quoted below.
Test-side (C#) driver class times out after 60 seconds of ChromeDriver inactivity and fails the test.

These "freezes" occur at random times, in random parts of the test suite. Sometime following a `ClickElement` command, sometimes following a `Navigate` command.

The line where the freeze occurs seems to always be similar to this:

```
[1580975930.724][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=265) 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "expression": "1"
```

C# timeout exception looks like this:

```
'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:25890/session/8ae62a10147ba1c9c0bc8f0ae6e47eed/element/fbd0ddbd-c198-4aa8-b05a-8a1d40766d83/click timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out'.
 Stack trace: 
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   ...
```

Log snippet from ChromeDriver:

```
[1580975930.723][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1580975930.723][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameScheduledNavigation 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "delay": 0,
   "frameId": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72",
   "reason": "formSubmissionPost",
   "url": "https://site-under-test/some-page"
}
[1580975930.724][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameRequestedNavigation 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "frameId": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72",
   "reason": "formSubmissionPost",
   "url": "https://site-under-test/some-page"
}
[1580975930.724][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameStartedLoading 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "frameId": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72"
}
[1580975930.724][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameClearedScheduledNavigation 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "frameId": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72"
}
[1580975930.724][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=265) 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "expression": "1"
}  

*******************************************************************
***** The line above is the one that freezes. Note timestamps *****
*******************************************************************

[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextDestroyed 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "executionContextId": 5
}
[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextsCleared 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {

}
[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.frameNavigated 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "frame": {
      "id": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72",
      "loaderId": "29E7B61049A044FA7CE34819B5BFA9B3",
      "mimeType": "text/html",
      "securityOrigin": "https://site-under-test",
      "url": "https://site-under-test/some-page"
   }
}
[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.executionContextCreated 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72",
         "isDefault": true,
         "type": "default"
      },
      "id": 6,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "https://site-under-test"
   }
}
[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: DOM.documentUpdated 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {

}
[1580976006.271][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: DOM.getDocument (id=266) 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {

}
[1580976006.272][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=265) 3DF35569FFFA4540EA485ED9C4383B72 {
   "result": {
      "description": "1",
      "type": "number",
      "value": 1
   }
}
```

How can I further investigate what the cause of the "freeze" is and fix it?

Comment: can you confirm if it is running fine on your local?

Comment: Thanks @KrunalPatel. I can't run the tests on my local machine due to security policies in the org. My "REPL" is code, push and watch results in Azure DevOps Server UI (sad LOL)

Comment: Ok, We can record screen for each test case on Azure DevOps. and see after test run. it might help to track it better. If you need any help how to achieve it let me know